# Disabling zooming on webview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I've searched around, but I couldn't find how to disable zooming in iOS.

I have this in my `viewDidLoad()` but it doesn't do anything.

```
webView.scrollView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `pinchGestureRecognizer` from `scrollView` in delegate method `didFinish navigation` by conforming your `ViewController` to `WKNavigationDelegate` as below,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // TODO: Initialize webView before setting the delegate
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if let pinchGesture = webView.scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer {
            webView.scrollView.removeGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        }
    }
}
```