# How to disable iOS pinch zoom and double tap zoom in Nativescript and plain JS

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript, zooming, pinchzoom

I've been unsuccessful in disabling zooming on iOS for a Nativescript web app written in plain JS. There seem to be TypeScript solutions for this, but I haven't been able to implement the same strategy in JS.

(1) Something like this, but in plain JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824238/3340040

NativeScript has a way of subclassing Objective-C classes, and exposing methods: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/ObjC-Subclassing#calling-base-methods-Exposed

...Which seems like it could work by extending the `UIViewController` (2): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229156/3340040

...But I'm stuck on how delegates are involved.

I feel like either of these two strategies should work, but for (1) I'm not sure how to convert all those `declare var` classes to JS that TS somehow gets for free. And strategy (2), I'm just out of my element.

Any NativeScripters out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to remove the typings from the original code then it's all just JavaScript.

```
let WebView = require("tns-core-modules/ui/web-view").WebView;

WebView.prototype.createNativeView = function () {
    let jScript = `var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
    meta.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);`;
    const wkUScript = WKUserScript.alloc().initWithSourceInjectionTimeForMainFrameOnly(jScript, WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
    const wkUController = WKUserContentController.new();
    wkUController.addUserScript(wkUScript);
    const configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration.new();
    configuration.userContentController = wkUController;
    configuration.preferences.setValueForKey(
        true,
        "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"
    );
    return new WKWebView({
        frame: CGRectZero,
        configuration: configuration
    });
};
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=xN6C3x)

**Note:** Remember to add platform check, the app will break if you run this iOS specific code on Android.

Comment: Thank you Manoj. This definitely works on my iPhone as well. And thanks for essentially answering the same question twice! Very much appreciated.